# python installed but not in /usr/bin

Tags: installation, python-install

I have installed python3 on SUSE 13.1 and then uninstalled it. I have also uninstalled python2.7. Then I've installed them again using zypper:

```
zypper install python
zypper install python3
```

The installation went fine, but the result is that I no longer have python in my /usr/bin, and I don't know how to start the interpreter at all.

```
whereis python
python: /usr/lib/python3.3 /usr/lib/python2.7
whereis python3
python3: /usr/lib/python3.3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Also:

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/python*: No such file or directory
```

I could manualy create link with `ln -s`, but I cannot even find where the binary file is.

Any help? Please.

Comment: I have installed python manually, downloaded from [official site](http://www.python.org/download/). Now I can run python, but I get the error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/etc/pythonstart", line 7, in <module>
    import readline
    ImportError: No module named readline

Comment: I had to install `readline-devel` and recompile. Now it seems to be ok.

Comment: No, it still sucks :( Now it doesn't recognize numpy, although I have installed it with `zypper`. I just want to get back to plain old python provided by suse repos.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy/rename the following file

```
cp /etc/python3start  /etc/pythonstart
```